# Storm bolt connecting to a database

Tags: apache-storm

I have a spout which reads from a source with 40K qps. 
I have two bolt, first one which reads from the source and does a database connection to build a cache which refreshes in every hour. The database has 2 connection open for a user so executor count that I have for this bolt is 2.

Other bolt is assigned 200 executors and 200 task to process the request.

I can't increase the connection to db. And I see that all the request is going to single workers. Other workers keep waiting and prints "0 send message".

```
kafkaSpoutConfigList:
  - executorsCount: 30
    taskCount: 30
    spoutName: 'kafka_consumer_spout'
    topicName: 'request'

processingBoltConfigList:
  - executorsCount: 2
    taskCount: 2
    boltName: 'db_bolt'
    boltClassName: 'com.Bolt1Class'
    boltSourceList:
      - 'kafka_consumer_spout'
  - executorsCount: 200
    taskCount: 200
    boltName: 'bolt2'
    boltClassName: 'com.Bolt2Class'
    boltSourceList:
      - 'db_bolt::streamx'

kafkaBoltConfigList:
  - executorsCount: 15
    taskCount: 15
    boltName: 'kafka_producer_bolt'
    topicName: 'consumer_topic'
    boltSourceList:
      - 'bolt2::Stream1'
  - executorsCount: 15
    taskCount: 15
    boltName: 'kafka_producer_bolt'
    topicName: 'data_test'
    boltSourceList:
      - 'bolt2::Stream2'
```

I am using localandgroupshuffling.

Answer (score 1):

When you use LocalOrShuffleGrouping, the following happens:

> If the target bolt has one or more tasks in the same worker process, tuples will be shuffled to just those in-process tasks. Otherwise, this acts like a normal shuffle grouping

So let's say your workers look like this:

```
worker1: {"bolt1 task 1", "bolt2 task 0-50"}
worker2: { "bolt1 task 2", "bolt2 task 50-100"}
worker3: { "bolt2 task 100-150"}
worker4: { "bolt2 task 150-200"}
```

In this case because you're telling Storm to use a local grouping when sending from bolt1 to bolt2, all the tuples will be going to worker 1 and 2. Worker 3 and 4 will be idle.

If you want to send tuples also to worker 3 and 4, you need to switch to shuffle grouping.